# CKeditor 4.x disable right click only on text no on images

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

We use CKeditor V4.0

I was able to disable right click with

CKEDITOR.replace(jQueryElm[0],{removePlugins: 'tableresize,tabletools,liststyle,tabletools,contextmenu' });

Is there a way to leave the right click on images only

[image]

I also tried removing the right click with

ev.editor.editable().addClass('cke_enable_context_menu')

But it didn't work.

Thanks

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

1. wait for the editor DOM to be ready by binding to `contentDom` event
2. bind to "contextmenu" event with highest priority by using 1 as the last parameter of `on` method
3. analyze event data and stop all handlers in the chain if it's not fired on `IMG`

Here's the code snippet:

```
editor.on( "contentDom", function() {
        editor.editable().on("contextmenu", function(ev) {
            var sel = editor.getSelection();
            if ( !(sel && !sel.isLocked) ) {
                retrun;
            }
            var el = sel.getStartElement();
            if (!(el&&el.is&&el.is("img"))) {
                ev.cancel();
                ev.stop();
            }
        }, null, null, 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, I get ev.data.$.explicitOriginalTarget || {}).tagName == undefined